# How to view Typescript code in Chrome with VS Code debugger

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools, visual-studio-code

I'm working on learning Angular2 by stepping through this program
https://github.com/start-angular/angular2-node-socket-io-chat-app

I'm using VS Code, and using the Debugger for Chrome. When I try debugging the code, and looking at the dev console in Chrome, I can't see the .ts files, only the .js files.
[image: Debugging the app in Chrome]

How do I see the .ts files? I've seen the .ts files (and hence was able to set breakpoints, etc) in other Angular2 projects.

Comment: you can accept my answer and upvote it if it helped then.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to allow source maps

```
"sourceMap": true
```

(it is set to false in the project you linked)

in tsconfig.

Then when you put debugger in your code it should take you to the typescript code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible becouse the typescript is compiled for the javascript.

You can try this command: `npm run tsc:w`.

This command compile in realtime your application. Here have working.

Comment: So start the app like the GitHub page says, then in another terminal, your command?

Comment: Yes, it's working for me. I am also learning and I used like this.

Comment: Alas, no. Can you document in detail the steps you took to get the above project I linked to work? So I can set breakpoints and see the .ts code in Chrome? Sorry I'm so new to Angular I don't know my way around.

Comment: Ok. Do You have other type for contact? I send my archives for you.